# Getting "data source type is not supported" while running macro to update a sheet linked to db by data connector

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to set up a macro to update a sheet on data from db and record the time of updation. i am getting an error when I try to run the macro.

From what I understand from Google, it is an authorization issue. I need this code to authorize users by itself and work.How do I add user authentication as part of this macro?

Error message:

> Exception: The data source type is not supported in Apps Script. (line 19, file "macros")
>
> line 19: spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();

```
function Timestamp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Americas_DB'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDataSourceTables().forEach(function(dataSourceTable) { dataSourceTable.waitForCompletion(300) });
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDataSourceTables().forEach(function(dataSourceTable) { dataSourceTable.waitForCompletion(300) });
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('EMEA_DB'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDataSourceTables().forEach(function(dataSourceTable) { dataSourceTable.waitForCompletion(300) });
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Timestamp'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Last updated');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=now()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
```

Comment: What DataSource are you using? is it from BigQuery?

Comment: No. SQL. @AndresDuarte

Comment: I'm referring to the DB you are using. As stated here [1], Apps Script only supports Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases. If your DB is not one of those, that's the reason of your problem. If it is one of those, can you post the part of code where you create the connection to your DB? [1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/

Comment: spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DB'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDataSourceTables().forEach(function(dataSourceTable) { dataSourceTable.waitForCompletion(300) });

Comment: To get the data source tables, you first have to insert a DataSourceTable to the sheet. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table